# How to trouble shoot arbitrary Linux programs

Tags: logs, debug

Currently I am trying to become better at using Linux and therefore I would like to know how Linux experts troubleshoot arbitrary programs.

On my new laptop I could not burn a cd via k3b. It just got stuck during the burning process and did not do anything any more... It created the isofile but did not start burning at all.

I did the following:

- redo everything to check if the error is reproducible
- see the logs via `journalctl` – nothing found
- looked out for specific k3b logs – did not find own log files
- checked if necessary cmd-line tools are installed and if the permissions are set correctly
- run k3b as root
- use another program (brasero) – worked – burned the discs

Then I tried many different things and found the bug coincidentally. I created a much bigger iso file from the original that was only 50 kb and then it worked.

My questions to the experts:

- Are there more sophisticated tools I could use?
- Could I have done something better?
- What would you have done?

Comment: Is the error reproducible? If so, did you report the bug?

Comment: @user535733 yes on my machine. But I did not report it yet.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I am currently using fedora and ubuntu but I noticed the bug on my fedora machine

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Determine the minimum number of steps required to reproduce the behavior from a stock new-install of Ubuntu.

Step 2: Spin up a Virtual Machine (unless your issue is hardware-related). See if you can reproduce the behavior in the latest release of Ubuntu. Or, better yet, in a pre-release daily build of Ubuntu.

- If the issue is hardware-related, boot from a new-release or daily .iso instead of using a VM.
- If you cannot reproduce the behavior in a new build, then the bug has likely already been fixed. Stop here.

Step 3: Review the bug reports for that software. If the issue has already been reported, help provide any additional information or testing that the developers need. If the issue is unreported, then report it. Monitor the bug report for information requests and testing requests from the developers.

- Similar bug reports and requests from the developers will inform you what kind of troubleshooting information is needed for your bug. There is no universal rule -- every bug is different. Some bugs require lots of trace information, others require almost none.
- There may be multiple Bub Trackers. Ubuntu has one, Debian has another, and the upstream project usually has it's own. Check them all!
- DON'T add "me too" and other irrelevant comments to a bug report. Keep it clean and on-topic. It's a *working notesheet* for developers to track and and fix bugs. I've seen progress on bugs slow (even stop) when the report became unreadable.

Step 4. Be patient. Some bugs get fixed in hours. Some take years.

OPTIONAL: If you want to dive into the codebase and fix the bug yourself, you certainly can. Create a patch or merge request, and add it to the bug report. Again, be patient: Other folks must test your patch before agreeing to include your code in their project.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and comment. What I initially was asking was do you use any more sophisticated tools in such a case except log files?

Comment: Depends upon what you are troubleshooting. The question title says "arbitrary." If others have reported a similar problem, and the developers have asked for specific information, then you follow that guidance.